# $_FILES Empty - Tearing my hair out

Tags: php, linux, whm

Had a form working fine (and still is) but files over a certain size just fail on an empty $_FILES.

I can upload 10Mb files, 60Mb and even 101MB but the file I really want to upload is 120MB and the upload just fails with an empty $_FILES.

```
The php.ini are set:
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
max_execution_time = 500
include_path = .:/usr/local/lib/php
auto_prepend_file = config.php
```

But the largest file just fails. I have read that my /tmp directory might be full but the only /tmp dir is in the same directory as public_html and this dir has not very much in it apart from awstats and webalizer.

Any help?

Comment: If you do a `phpinfo()` is that definitely the php.ini that gets used? (Long shot I know)

Comment: Guys - have you read the question? I think he already knows of `upload_max_filesize`...

Comment: @simone: serious? where does it say that?

Comment: Yeah I would do a `phpinfo()` to make sure the php.ini file is being used and that the values are being set correctly. Also do you have access to logs? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hint 1: [`max_input_time`](http://php.net/max_input_time) - see our nice site: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+max_input_time --- Hint 2: Do error logging. Look inside your PHP error log. *"Just Fails"* is not a proper error description if you're looking for help. Hint 3: Other PHP extensions might interfer with your configuration. E.g. security protections. You find out with PHP error logging. Hint 4: Check the server error log in case your server brings the request to an end. Then this is unrelated to PHP.

Comment: can you please post section `Server API` from your phpinfo

Answer (score 1):

check this setting `max_input_time` . it limits the time a script can parse data.

Comment: Will do that now - nope! Checked my phpinfo to make sure it was accepted. Set it at max_input_time = 500

Comment: 800M. These values are just huge to make sure that there will be no problem. I can reduce them after it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody says that your `memory_limit` needs to be raised either.

It should be higher than `upload_max_filesize`.

If your are running suhosin there are also some options: `suhosin.memory_limit`, `suhosin.post.max_value_length`

Additionally there is the `max_input_time` option.

There could also be some proxies like nginx or varnish which prevents uploading such big files.

Finally there is one directive in Apache: `LimitRequestBody`

And for mod_fastcgi: `FcgidMaxRequestLen`, `FcgidConnectTimeout`

You can also try monitoring your upload with APC and some AJAX driven progress bar: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads/3

Answer (score 0):

Are u using "MAX_FILE_SIZE" hidden field in the input file upload html form?

If used please check this issue.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#74692

Answer (score -2):

Set these in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

and check

```
memory_limit
```

to be higher than post_max_size

Comment: @rmccallum Eww sorry, edited it. I somehow missed those 2 lines. Try to raise the memory limit of the script.